# Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar de una form a otra. LLamo desde MenuForm a otra llamada "EmfermoRep", cosa que esta bien, pero el problema viene cuando quiero ir de vuelta desde "EnfermoRep" a "MenuForm". Traté de agregar un botón e instanciar "MenuForm", pero me manda ese error que es un loop infinito. Algunas ideas para volver, les agradecería mucho :D!

```
public partial class MenuForm : Form
    {

        Ventanas v = new Ventanas();
        EnfermoRep reporteEnfermo = new EnfermoRep();
        public MenuForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void rptEnfermo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            v.CargarVentana(reporteEnfermo, this.panel1);
        }
    }
```

Clase EnfermoRep:

```
public partial class EnfermoRep : Form
    {

        Ventanas v = new Ventanas();
        MenuForm menuForm = new MenuForm();
        public EnfermoRep()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EnfermoRep_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bd.Enfermo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.EnfermoTableAdapter.Fill(this.bd.Enfermo);

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

        private void btnVolver1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            v.CargarVentanas(menuForm, this.enfermoRep);
        }
    }
```

Cabe mencionar que creé una clase llamada ventanas, la cual me permite moverme en Forms a través de paneles (Osea el programa solo tiene una Form principal, la cual llama a otras pero con paneles, sin nunca salirse de la principal) No se si me doy a entender -.-'

Esta es la clase que permite eso:

```
class Ventanas
    {
        public void CargarVentana(object sonform, Panel panel)
        {
            panel.Controls.Clear();
            Form fh = sonform as Form;
            fh.TopLevel = false;
            fh.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panel.Controls.Add(fh);
            panel.Tag = fh;
            fh.Show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar el `new` para crear una nueva instancia del form padre si quieres comnicarte con uan instancia existente, debes pasar esa instancia, el tema es que lo complicas al programar con paneles y forms, porque no usaste `User Controls` los controles de usuario son como forms sin bordes y se puede ubicar mejor dentro de un panel.

```
public partial class MenuForm : Form
{

    public MenuForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void rptEnfermo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnfermoRep reporteEnfermo = new EnfermoRep();
        Ventanas.CargarVentana(reporteEnfermo, this, this.panel1);
    }
} 

public partial class EnfermoRep : Form
{


    public EnfermoRep()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EnfermoRep_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bd.Enfermo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.EnfermoTableAdapter.Fill(this.bd.Enfermo);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void btnVolver1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = this.Owner as Form;
        frm.Show();

        this.Close();
    }
}



class Ventanas
{
    public static void CargarVentana(Form sonform, Form owner, Panel panel)
    {
        sonform.TopLevel = false;
        sonform.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        sonform.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel.Controls.Add(fh);

        sonform.Show(owner);
    }
}
```

aplique cambios en el codigo

Analiza como se define el `owner` para poder determinar quie es el parent del form que abres y asi poder volver
Pero el volver cierra ese form, lo que habria que validar si el cierre lo quita del Panel, sino lo hace deberia pasarse la instancia del panel para poder hacer el remove del Panel.Controls